# Setting up SVN on MediaTemple?

Tags: svn, mediatemple

I want to setup my own SVN server on a dedicated plan over at MediaTemple. This would help me immensely when updating / checking out code with the staff I work with in India. I can't find anything good on the web, and I'm sure someone here knows what to do. How can I set up a SVN server on my dedicated so I can create multiple repositories? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard subversion book is always the starting point (of course); the notes on setting up Svn over an Apache server can be found in chapter 6.

The SVN server itself is pretty easy; it's the Apache admin and permissions issues that can get you in trouble.  Unfortunately you're right that there's a shortage of examples online.  I've found one decent example LAMP svn/trac setup. (It's actually a walkthrough of an Ubuntu server install, but on the way it takes you through Apache/PHP/SVN/Trac; it may give you some 
ideas.)

http://jakeyoon.com/2009/12/30/build-ubuntu-server-9-10-64-bit-all-in-one-lamp-server-linux-apache-mysql-php-subversion-trac-and-samba-part-1/

There's also a basic svn/apache walkthrough on howtoforge.com at /apache_subversion_repository

Also, if that's all you want the server for, you could consider using a dedicated SVN host instead - Assembla is an obvious example, but lots of sites exist.